# Make a date as string which formatted as the same in the pivot item format

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, excel-2010

[image]

I have a pivot table with a beginning condition is something like that.

And I already have an array as rgTglval variable, when if I looped to each item of rgTglVal with this code `For Each el In rgTglVal: next`the value of el in the Locals Window is like this : #04-Jun-2022#, #10-Jun-2022# and so on.

Based on each value of the array, I want to select the range of NOTA field by offseting the labelrange of the pivot items in TGL column.

```
For Each el In rgTglVal
    With pt.PivotFields("TGL")
        X = Format(el, "dd-mmm-yy")
        X = Replace(X, "-", "/") '--> this give me a string value in the kind "dd/mmm/yy"
        .PivotItems(X).LabelRange.Offset(0, 2).Select 'expected final result
    End With
Next
```

The code works as expected because before I wrote the code above, I check first how the value of pivot item in TGL field is formatted by using this kind of code : `For Each pit In pt.PivotFields("TGL").PivotItems: Exit For: Next` so I can see the pit string value is like this "19/Mar/14". So it's formatted as text in the kind "dd/mmm/yy".

My question :
Using the el value from rgTglVal as the value of the pivot items in TGL field, how do I get the expected final result without the need to know manually on how the pivot items of the TGL field is formatted ?

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

I make the question shorter, but it seems it still difficult to be understodd by my reader.

Assumed that the column TGL is not a date but a string... aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd and so on. So if I want to get the range of NOTA where the pivot item is aaa, I can just do with : `pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems("aaa").labelrange.offset(0,2).select` --> this will select nota PB220520029 and PB-220521003 range.

and if I want the range of NOTA where the pivot item is bbb, I can just do with
`pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems("bbb").labelrange.offset(0,2).select` --> this will select nota PB220524026, PB-220528029 and PB-220531038.

and so on.

But since the TGL field data are dates, `pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems(#04-Jun-22#).labelrange.offset(0,2).select` won't work, because as long as I know, the pivotitems need to be a string. #04-Jun-22# is a date, the el value of the rgTglVal array.

Even if I convert it to string, like this :
`pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems(format(#6/4/22#, "dd-mmm-yy")).labelrange.offset(0,2).select` it may work - it may not work, because the string of the pivot items maybe "dd-mmm-yy", it maybe "dd/mmm/yy", etc depends on how the number format of the TGL field is set in the pivot field setting ---> so this is because I don't know on how to code so it **automatically** adjust the el value (a date) to whatever model of the pivot items string is formatted by the app.

The only thing I am able to know how the string is formatted for the date pivot item by the app is by step run `For Each pit In pt.PivotFields("TGL").PivotItems: Exit For: Next` then see **manually** how the pit value is formatted in the Locals Window.

Only after I **manually** see the looped pit value in the Locals Window is (for example) like this "19/Mar/14". So then I know that I should do the code like this : `pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems(format(el, "dd/mmm/yy")).labelrange.offset(0,2).select`

Comment: Perhaps consider [shortening your question?](https://i.imgflip.com/6l1msa.jpg)

Comment: @pgSystemTester, sorry if it's too long because I want to be clear as much as possible. The short question is the title of my question. Thank you.

Comment: not really getting to the question here.  Why do you want to be able to format a date the same as the pivot?  if that is a date in the underlying data then it is still stored as a number (i.e. 27/06/2022, today, is 44,739) and you can do manipulation based on that, also you could change the formatting in the pivot table output.  If it's not stored as a date but as a string then you will have to work out how it appears to be able to compare to it.

Comment: @user1236777, Because to get the range of the pivot item in TGL field, I thought the pivot item value must be a string.

Comment: hionestly i'm not following why that would be and I'm not certain what formula you're using but if you need the TGL in a certain format why not just change its format prior to referencing it?  you could even take its current format and reapply it after doing whatever you're doing so that the user would never see a change

Comment: @user1236777, I am very sorry as to be honest it's difficult for me to explain it in English. You wrote _"if you need the TGL in a certain format why not just change its format prior to referencing it?"_ .... on the contrary, I'm expecting that without changing the TGL field format, the code to get the labelrange of the pivot item in TGL field `pt.pivotfields("TGL").pivotitems(X).labelrange.select` where X is a string value formatted to whatever the format of the pivot item for TGL field Excel made by default - run without error.

Comment: but if you dont know the field format how would you make that string?

Comment: That's my point. I wonder if there is a code which can know how Excel by default format those date pivot items as a string in TGL field. My English is limited, but do you mind if we continue in the chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245992/discussion-between-user1236777-and-karma).